# Suspicious behavior from explorer.exe

Tags: windows

The explorer.exe process on my computer is repeatedly trying to connect with some kind of remote host, I do not know exactly what this process is trying to do.

**Why do I suspect Explorer.exe ?**
First my computer screen turns to black for 3 second then blinks and turns to black again. Finally everything goes "Reversed/Mirrored" like what you see when you go to Control Panel -> appearance and personalization -> Display -> change Display settings -> Orientation (Flipped)
I began to think that my PC is hacked!

I used TCP View utility and noticed that explorer.exe tries to connect using local port starting with 6, "65321" for example, and the remote port also starts with 6 but those two ports keep changing with each attempt. And in the state column I see "SYN_SENT"
Is this normal behavior from Explorer.exe process ?

Comment: Which Windows version do you use?

Comment: when you log into windows, do you log in as an admin?

Comment: I use Windows 7 ultimate [7601 Service Pack 1 6.1.7601]
and yes my user account is administrator

Comment: Ignore the local port; practically all outgoing TCP connections (and some UDP also) use a unique local port assigned from the "ephemeral" range, which on Windows (except unsupported XP and earlier) is normally 49152 to 65535. The *remote* address(es?) and port(s) could be relevant.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Do you think this is normal behavior from Explorer.exe ?

Comment: You need to specify what the remote address is before we can tell you the answer to that.

Comment: I have no idea; I've never noticed explorer.exe trying to connect to somewhere that doesn't respond, but I've never spent time watching it either. In general any repeated connection attempts that don't complete are worth looking at.

Comment: The remote address is 'localhost' and the protocol is TCP

Comment: I'm not convinced the display issues you're seeing have anything to do with explorer.exe. Sounds more like a problem with your display hardware or driver.

Comment: Maybe it's not related to Explorer.exe problem, But why Explorer.exe does this is it normal behavior? is it normal to Explorer.exe to connect or tries to listen for incoming connection? Why Explorer.exe use internet connection in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a Trojan on your computer. This is called the "HijackThis" Trojan, and is very damaging to your computer. I recommend running [Bitdefender](http://bitdefender.com) and [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org) full system scan to eliminate this problem. If it does not fix it, your last resort would be a full system refresh.

Comment: Source: http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/150943-syn-sent-is-it-a-virus/